# WebView game files load, but game doesn't start

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am loading a page with a `WebView`, and in the `WebView` I load an iframe that has a canvas which loads a game. I am not sure why, but the game doesn't load. In the console I can see that it outputs http requests to the files it needs to run the game but once it is all complete I am left with a black empty screen. If I open the same URL in the emulator web browser the game loads and it is playable. What can I do to make it playable in the app?

```
public class Play extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("gameUrl");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        // Setup the WebView
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.gameWebView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        System.out.println(url);

        // Load a default URL into the webview
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Here is the output when the page loads:

```
    --------- beginning of system
09-13 19:54:34.894 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
09-13 19:54:34.895 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
09-13 19:54:34.897 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/System.out: http://dev.gamesmart.com/mobile/play/gamesmart/tower-of-babel
09-13 19:54:35.961 5435-5476/com.gamesmart.gamesmart E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae473ed0
09-13 19:54:36.170 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 5435
09-13 19:54:36.807 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(29)] "mjs_game_id:", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (29)
09-13 19:54:36.807 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(30)] "mjs_portal_id:", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (30)
09-13 19:54:36.808 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(31)] "mjs_branding_id:", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (31)
09-13 19:54:36.808 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(32)] "mjs_ad_id:", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (32)
09-13 19:54:36.898 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(449)] "no localstorage found", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (449)
09-13 19:54:36.902 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(573)] "prepare Change Username form ...", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (573)
09-13 19:54:36.905 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(608)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (608)
09-13 19:54:36.928 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1105)] "serving universal version ...", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (1105)
09-13 19:54:36.957 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(587)] "AdInGamePreroll disabled in CMS ...", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (587)
09-13 19:54:36.961 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(636)] "changing orientation ...", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (636)
09-13 19:54:37.085 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
09-13 19:54:37.098 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Initial: Tracks: 1 Format: {csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=3771,capacity=3771], mime=audio/vorbis, durationUs=838662, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=30,capacity=30], channel-count=1, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.108 5435-5653/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
09-13 19:54:37.177 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: output format changed to {channel-count=1, what=1869968451, mime=audio/raw, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.177 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Final:  Rate: 44100 Channels: 1 Mime: audio/vorbis Duration: 838662 microsec
09-13 19:54:37.315 5435-5457/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Initial: Tracks: 1 Format: {csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=3365,capacity=3365], mime=audio/vorbis, durationUs=862040, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=30,capacity=30], channel-count=1, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.319 5435-5660/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
09-13 19:54:37.352 5435-5470/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/MediaResourceGetter: no ethernet/wifi connection detected
09-13 19:54:37.352 5435-5470/com.gamesmart.gamesmart W/MediaResourceGetter: non-file URI can't be read due to unsuitable network conditions
09-13 19:54:37.352 5435-5470/com.gamesmart.gamesmart E/MediaResourceGetter: Unable to configure metadata extractor
09-13 19:54:37.365 5435-5457/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: output format changed to {channel-count=1, what=1869968451, mime=audio/raw, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.365 5435-5457/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Final:  Rate: 44100 Channels: 1 Mime: audio/vorbis Duration: 862040 microsec
09-13 19:54:37.423 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Initial: Tracks: 1 Format: {csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=4225,capacity=4225], mime=audio/vorbis, durationUs=862040, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=30,capacity=30], channel-count=2, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.428 5435-5663/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
09-13 19:54:37.450 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: output format changed to {channel-count=2, what=1869968451, mime=audio/raw, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.453 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Final:  Rate: 44100 Channels: 2 Mime: audio/vorbis Duration: 862040 microsec
09-13 19:54:37.494 5435-5457/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Initial: Tracks: 1 Format: {csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=3365,capacity=3365], mime=audio/vorbis, durationUs=501904, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=30,capacity=30], channel-count=1, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.499 5435-5666/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
09-13 19:54:37.514 5435-5457/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: output format changed to {channel-count=1, what=1869968451, mime=audio/raw, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.514 5435-5457/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Final:  Rate: 44100 Channels: 1 Mime: audio/vorbis Duration: 501904 microsec
09-13 19:54:37.530 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Initial: Tracks: 1 Format: {csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=4225,capacity=4225], mime=audio/vorbis, durationUs=626938, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=30,capacity=30], channel-count=2, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.533 5435-5669/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
09-13 19:54:37.542 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: output format changed to {channel-count=2, what=1869968451, mime=audio/raw, sample-rate=44100}
09-13 19:54:37.543 5435-5458/com.gamesmart.gamesmart D/WebAudioMediaCodec: Final:  Rate: 44100 Channels: 2 Mime: audio/vorbis Duration: 626938 microsec
09-13 19:55:07.828 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(292)] "MarketJS API Log Time Spent: ", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (292)
09-13 19:55:07.963 5435-5435/com.gamesmart.gamesmart I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(300)] "200", source: http://mjs.gamesmart.com/serve?portal_id=5269991175749632&game_id=5656313283477504&branding_id=4751999195152384&ad_id=6127931696873472&portal_localization_id=4958697046409216 (300)
```

Comment: Does url needs internet access? given permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yeah it does, and It has that permission. I have another activity that access the internet with a webview, and that page loads fine.

Comment: can we check errors ? @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: I printed it out to the console instead, so the above is all that happens once the activity loads

Comment: If I hit that url in web view on android project . I can see a Start button. Click on start button it plays a mp3 file but UI is blank as you said.. with below errors in logs MediaPlayer(4160): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

Comment: 09-14 22:47:17.286: D/MediaPlayerBridge(5063): getLocalPlayer() = android.media.MediaPlayer@41fe7180
09-14 22:47:17.286: E/MediaPlayer(5063): setDataSource: IOException! uri=http://whitelabel-cdn.marketjs.com/games/tower-of-babel/localization/en/media/music/sunlight2537.mp3
09-14 22:47:17.286: D/MediaPlayer(5063): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
09-14 22:47:17.286: D/MediatekClassFactory(5063): createInstance(): Begin = 3034826
09-14 22:47:17.286: D/MediatekClassFactory(5063): create Instance with :  interface com.mediatek.common.media.IOmaSettingHelper

Comment: 09-14 22:47:17.287: W/MediatekClassFactory(5063): OP not exist!, Get obj from default class